# How make simple div box repeater jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

how can i make simple div box repeater with jquery

```
> <div class="mybox"> <input name="name[]"  /> <input name="number[]" 
> /> <input name="text[]"  /> </div>and
```

I have div box with fields , i need that i can add same div box with +
like on this pic  [image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: Look for jQuery [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create template of the input elements and add it to parent-container. I have created below template.

```
var content = "<div class='container'><input type='text'/><input type='number' /><input type='text'/><button type='button' id='remove'>-</button></div>";
```

```js
var content = "<div class='container'><input type='text'/><input type='number' /><input type='text'/><button type='button' id='remove'>-</button></div>";

$(".parent-container").html(content);

$("#add").on("click", function(){
 if($(".parent-container").children().length <5){
   $(".parent-container").append(content);
  }
  if($(".parent-container").children().length == 5){
   $("#add").hide();
  }
});

$(".parent-container").on("click", "#remove", function(){
 $(this).parent().remove(); 
   $("#add").show();
});
```

```css
.parent-container{
  height:auto;
}

.container{
  border:1px solid lightblue;
  width:180px;
  margin:5px 0;
  position:relative;
}

.container > input {
  display:block;
  margin:5px 0;
}

.container > button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-container">

</div>
<button type='button' id='add'>+</button>
```

Test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/vh6f50yc/1/)

**Update 1:**

Add up to 5..
Test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/vh6f50yc/3/)

Comment: How can make maximum + 5 times

Comment: i add JavaScript in this  script tag but it do not works

Comment: I have updated the answer.. Please accept it if you feel it fixes your problem so that it will be helpful to other.